# BCB swprintf not working

Tags: c++, c, c++builder

Anyone else encountered a problem like this?

```
swprintf_s(v, len, L"%ws", var);
MessageBox(NULL, v, NULL' NULL);
```

Message box prints out "%ws" not the contents of var.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++Builder does not support all of the size prefixes that Visual Studio supports (and vice versa).  In this case, C++Builder does not support the `w` prefix for `%s`, but Visual Studio does.

Visual Studio:

[Format Specification Syntax: printf and wprintf Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx)

> A format specification, which consists of optional and required fields, has the following form:
>
> ```
> %[flags] [width] [.precision] [{h | l | ll | w | I | I32 | I64}] type
> ```

C++Builder:

[printf Format Specifiers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Printf_Format_Specifiers)

> Print format specifiers have the following form:
>
> ```
> % [flags] [width] [.prec] [F|N|h|l|L] type_char
> ```

If `var` is a wide string, you can use `%s` or `%ls` in both compilers.